# Oracle APEX - validating IG selection on submit

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive Grid on my page that allows the rows to be selected. When the user clicks on the button, the page branches out to another page. I need to create a validation to ensure the page only branches out if some records were selected. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: To what page do you branch ? A predefined page or a page from your table ? It would also help knowing if you accept multiple selected row and what you want to do if it happens if so.

Comment: pre-defined page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no pretension my way is the best way, but it works:

You'll need to give your button a static ID (mine will be `LinkButton`).

You should then create a Dynamic Action on your grid on the event `Selection change [Interactive Grid]`. Make a True Action that `Execute JavaScript Code`, that code bit should do :

```
if(this.data.selectedRecords[0] != undefined) {
    //This is what happens when rows are selected
    document.getElementById("LinkButton").disabled = false;
}
else {
    //This is what happens when no rows are selected
    document.getElementById("LinkButton").disabled = true;
}
```

**Probably not the best solution, there most likely is a way of achieving this using the `Grid Widget` from [APEX'S API](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/520052/files/static/v56/jsdoc/grid.html), but I wasn't able to return any object from my grid using it. My answer would disable the button if any row is selected in any grid (if you have multiple reports/grids that is) in that page, instead of in a specific Interative Grid.

My answer was highly inspired by this person: http://thejavaessentials.blogspot.com/2017/03/getting-selected-rows-in-oracle-apex.html and this post : [Disabling and enabling a html input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460511/oracle-apex-validating-ig-selection-on-submit)

**I tested it on APEX 19.1, but as the person above was working on APEX 5, my guess is that it should work on it too.